# Link to Apple Wallet or Android Pay from a MVC Web Application

Tags: android, ios, api, model-view-controller, android-pay

I’m looking for a way to add Apple Wallet/Android Pay links with in a web application (https://www.somewebsite.com) where I can pass membership card parameters (card name, member name, card number).  Is this possible? I have found some examples within mobile apps but nothing from a browser to mobile app.

Answer (score 1):

For Apple Wallet take a look at this [Apple Developer PassKit](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/PassKit_PG/DistributingPasses.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012195-CH11-SW1)

> Your website and email can use the Add to Wallet badge to give your users a visual queue to add the pass to Wallet. For more information, see the Add to Apple Wallet Badge section of the Developer website. To create buttons for your app, use the PKAddPassButton class.

and for Android Pay [Google Developer](https://developers.google.com/android-pay/mobile-web/mobile-web-overview) and [Android Pay UI Branding](https://developers.google.com/android-pay/ui-branding)

Answer (score 0):

For Android you can integrate using Payment request API. It is supporting Chrome browser.

https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/discovery-and-monetization/payment-request/android-pay

https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/discovery-and-monetization/payment-request/